# Trying to undersatand join() method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code

```
class Multi extends Thread{  

 public void run(){  
  for(int i=1;i<=3;i++){  

  System.out.println(i + ": "+Thread.currentThread().getName());  
  }  
 }  
public static void main(String args[]){  
 Multi t1=new Multi();
 t1.setName("First Thread");
 Multi t2=new Multi();
 t2.setName("Second Thread");
 Multi t3=new Multi();  
 t3.setName("Third Thread");
 t1.start();  
 t2.start();  
 try{  
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
 }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  

 t3.start();  
 }  
}
```

**

The output varies every time I run :

```
1st time Output

1: Second Thread
2: Second Thread
3: Second Thread
1: First Thread
2: First Thread
3: First Thread
1: Third Thread
2: Third Thread
3: Third Thread


=============================================
2nd time Output

1: First Thread
2: First Thread
3: First Thread
1: Second Thread
2: Second Thread
3: Second Thread
1: Third Thread
2: Third Thread
3: Third Thread


*************************************************
```

Since `t2.join()` is called after `t1.join()` how come 1st output is coming ? Shouldn't `t2` wait for `t1` to execute?

Please help me understand the `join()` method behavior, if possible with more code snippet examples

Comment: To get the behaviour you expect you would need to call `t2.start()` *after* `t1.join()`. In your current code, the two threads run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for editing :) I was about to do that

Answer (score 7):

`t.join()` blocks the *current* thread (the main thread in your example) until the thread `t` has finished executing. It doesn't block any other thread, and doesn't prevent any other thread to run.

Your example starts t1 and t2. So t1 and t2 run in parallel. And the main thread blocks until t1 is completed. Once t1 is completed, it blocks until t2 is completed. t2 might very well has finished executing before t1. In this case, `t2.join()` will return immediately.

Answer (score 2):

The [`join` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) doesn't affect the order of execution of any currently executing `Thread`s.  All it does it make the current thread wait until the `Thread` specified ends.

Answer (score 2):

For Thread `t2` to wait for `t1` to finish off.. you need to write `t1.join()` in the `run()` method for `t2`.

In your case, **main thread will wait for t1 and t2 to finish off** and it will then start thread `t3`. This is evident from the output which clearly shows that t3 had started after t1 and t2 got completed.

Answer (score 1):

The output will vary because it can be predicted how `t1` and `t2` threads will work behind the scene. That's how threads work on JVM by default. It has nothing to do with your `join()` methods. In your case when you call `t1.join()` it only means that the "main" thread will wait until `t1` thread will finish its job. The same is about `t2.join()`